# I can no longer get smooth playback in video editor after 3.1 update. Anyway to fix this?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, versions, frame-rate

Hi I recently downloaded Blender 3.1 and I'm now having problems with the video editor.  I know 3.1 has a feature that automatically creates a proxy but since I'm used creating it on my own I changed the setting in system preferences: proxy setup to manual.  Anyway after the proxy is done rebuilding  I can scrub through it without audio fine until I try to play the video in normal time.  It will play in normal time after chugging a bit but after that I can't scrub through it smoothly anymore.  I've found a partial fix that if under playback I change the sync to frame dropping or play every frame I can now scrub smoothly again but I would really like to be able to use sync to audio and scrub smoothly like I could before I updated.  I previously had an older version of blender (2.8 or so I believe)  If anyone could help me I'd appreciate it!

Comment: Does it help if you turn off the audio waveform? I don't think it gets baked down to proxy but it does cache and may fill up ram?

Comment: The audio strip doesn't have the waveform on it.  I tried adding it but it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem.  I highlight the audio strip and then on the right select the strip tab and then click on source and then check the caching box.  This loads the audio into ram and allows me to scrub smoothly again.

Comment: I noticed that when I load gopro footage I don't have this problem.  It only happens with gaming footage I recorded with OBS.

Comment: OBS can record at variable frame rates. Blender does not like this. You'd find that it plays better after transcoding to a regular frame rate. Also the Codec might be to heavy for Blender to play back easily.